# In PC Chrome Inspect view everything is perfect but from mobile it's not responsive

Tags: html, css

I build a form using HTML CSS js jquery and GSAP. When I debug with chrome console. It's showing perfectly, but visiting from mobile is broken. I used media query but it's coming out broken so I removed it. How to make it responsive in mobile view also.

```
*{

    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    

body{

   font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
   background-color: #000000;
   background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #000000 0%, #414141 74%);   
}

#msform {

    width: 900px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
    
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding: 20px 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 10%;
    border:solid 2px white;
    position: relative;
}
```

You can see my live form in github- https://tamzid958.github.io/multipage_form/

Comment: `#msform {width: 900px}` kinda destroys any possible hope of responsive design here.

Comment: then should I use width:50% like this?

Comment: No, something like `max-width: 900px;`

Comment: and `<input type="checkbox" class="bcheck" name="regulardonate" value="yes">` is overflowing because it has `width: 100%`

Comment: thanks, I fixed it. I have another problem with collecting data and sending mail. I will open a new question :)